# Oracle Apex License fees

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-xe

Do you think that apex is a good choice for programs which are made to small size companies. For example I will develop a web application to a high school. They can not pay money to Oracle 10g or Oracle 11g license. So I must find cheap and rapid solutions.
Can I use Oracle XE and Apex for corporate applications without paying any money?

And I do not know whether I need to pay money foran application server?(like IIS,Apacahe, Tomcat...)

Answer (score 3):

Apex is inside Oracle XE, you can upgrade it to Apex 4.0 if you want...
At the end, you won't get any technical support if you don't have a valid paid license.
So as long as you stick to Oracle XE (free) and Apex running with this, you are legal.

Upgrading Oracle Application Express within Oracle Database 10g Express Edition (XE)
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/upgrade-apex-for-xe-154969.html

Apex 4.0
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you can use Oracle APEX with Oracle XE for corporate applications, you can also use [Oracle APEX Listener](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex-listener/downloads/index.html) as your web server.

The only problem would be the hardware limits imposed on the XE edition:

*"Oracle Database XE can be installed on any size host machine with any number of CPUs (one database per machine), but XE will store up to 11GB of user data, use up to 1GB of memory, and use one CPU on the host machine..."*

But that should be enough to start, and when you start needing more resources you can also try [Amazon on-demand DB instances](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/#pricing) "*On-Demand DB Instances for the License Included model let you pay for compute capacity by the hour your DB Instance runs with no long-term commitments..."*